# How to get URL of existing Amazon S3 object inside a private bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Kotlin to create an app like Tiktok which requires video hosting somewhere. I am using Amazon SDK and able to generate presigned url once the video is uploaded into Amazon S3.

My issue is, the presigned url expires max within 7 days. How can I generate another URL for the object already exist inside Amazon S3...

I know I can access it if I make my bucket and videos public but is there a way without making them public?

It may be a stupid question but I'm new to Amazon S3 and unable to find answer for it.

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Regenerate the pre-signed URL, there’s no other way

Comment: How do ppl access the objects? Directly, with the link only, or through your application? If the second, the application must generate new url that you show user each time they want to access the objects.